# css : layout Question

Tags: css, scrollbar

I have a css layout where in I have a single page website

the problem is I did not want the scrollbar so i did overflow hidden and the it worked fine but when there is different screen resolution, so content in the bottom is cut off is there any way to work around this

I mean the website should not have a scrollbar when the things fit on the first page but then when there is not enough room for the content the scrollbar should appear

Comment: "single website" - what website?  "...did not want the slider" - what slider? Please give some more context and show us your code. A link to the live site should be nice too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `overflow:auto;` not `overflow:hidden;`.

`overflow:auto;` will return a scrollbar when needed, and won't when it isn't.

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up my formatting. I was posting from my iPhone and can't get the usual formatting to work right.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `overflow:auto;` instead.
My recommendation is to use fixed width and minimum height to your body (or main container)
that way the browser will add is own scrolls if needed. you can read about fixed width here http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/ht/htcsscenterfix.htm

Comment: +1 for deciphering the question; I thought OP meant a "range" slider. O.o

Comment: this seems to be the right answer, but... uh, isn't it the default anyway?